# Text adding issue into the string

Tags: c#, string

Hello guys I am retriving a mail and add to the some perticular string,

but the time of the inserting the content it will give me error like this.

text/html; ISO-8859-1

so how I can resolve this.

Thanks[image]

I am attching image of error so just see it and what is the solution for this.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should include "charset" in the string:

```
contentTypeString = "text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1";
```

Comment: @Pabuc: yes, saw that; I looked in the code above where there are quotation marks, but that does not seem to be in the current code path.

Answer (score 2):

The content type string is not in a correct format according to the MIME standard so the ContentType class is not able to parse it.

`text/html; ISO-8859-1` is not valid. It should be `text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1`

See [RFC2045](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2045) for more information about the exakt syntax of the Content-Type header.

Answer (score 1):

The screenshot indicates that your `contentTypeString` has ended up being `text/html; ISO-8859-1`.

You are missing `charset=` before the `ISO-8859-1`.